# MySQL mixed table query

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am not an SQL magician so I'm venturing to ask for help. I have 4 tables to insert into a 5th one while checking a 6th table to ensure no duplicates. For example, no names in the 6th table can be inserted in the 5th one. I probably can try to figure out the best SQL query for the job but my head can't get around the right method? The final table size is small for now (5000 contact names), but will grow every month so I got to start right. I plan to use a PHP script with mysql connection to the database. This script will only run on my server (CenTOS 5).

Comment: Can you tell use what your current schema is? We will be able to help then.

Comment: I think you better at least add some structure for the tables if you want people to write your code for you - but better yet, add in the query that you have so far, you might only be a few characters off getting it right.

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing the schema, in general if you're going to prevent rows from entering tables based on other tables - in mySQL you'll need to utilize foreign keys.  Overall, all of this will need to be done in a database transaction so that whatever logic you create in PHP to insert rows in various tables either succeed after total confirmation of success or fail and roll back to the prior state.

Comment: Wow, a downvote for some simple advice on best practices on an incredibly ambiguous question...